# PHP regxp password validation seeking explanation

Tags: php, regex

Yo all,

So i am learning regexp :-)  yay

I am learning how to parse password strings that have to have 1 capital letter and 1 number atleast, and can be between 6 to 12 chars long.

Im having troble understanding this.

```
$array = array("Hallo1ween23");

$match = preg_grep('%^(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[A-Z])(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[a-z])(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[0-9])\S{6,12}$%',$array);

foreach($match as $value) {
    echo "<pre>" .$value . "<br>";
}
```

So basicly i understand these parts:

**Example of what i do know:**

This line `%(?<=mail)man%` looks for a word that starts with `mail` and ends with `man`

Ok so.. `(?=[a-z]*?[A-Z])` a simplyfied version but still the same kinda logic.  I dont understand that.

So i broke the whole line up in 3 if it helps.

These next two i dont get.

```
(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[A-Z])
(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[a-z])
```

I know that \s means whitespace, and \s means nonwhitespace, but i dont really understand the purpose of it here.

```
(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[0-9])\S
```

This is the min and max letters accepted.

```
{6,12}
```

Some explanation would be neat.

thanks in advance :-)

**@Tafari**

Basicly this is the line.

```
(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[A-Z])
```

And the `\S`  at the end of the whole regexp line.

I do understand `[-_a-zA-Z0-9]`

* means zero or more

? means we are not sure if its there or not

Putting it all together i loose that one.

Comment: There is a wonderful tut on regexp for beginners here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/

Comment: Just state what parts (make a list just containing the regex parts without any description) you do not understand and I'll try to explain them a bit later as in 10 mins I will have some work.

Comment: I will add at the buttom a new area of the kind you requested :)

Comment: I, myself, learned regex on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), it is the best tuto out there, but it need some time to get it all...

Comment: The regex makes no sense to me. It will always match `\S{6,12}` regardless, so everything before `\S{6,12}$` is useless.

Comment: @gwillie "\S{6,12}" everything before this is needed since i need to check for some sort of password checking.  This is what my question is all about.  Please read it again, and you will find that you read it to fast the first time :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the following for starters [`Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)...

The following assertions are recognized.

```
(?!)  - Negative Lookahead     foo(?!bar)  matches foo when not followed by bar
(?=)  - Positive Lookahead     foo(?=bar)  matches foo when followed by bar
(?<!) - Negative Lookbehind    (?<!foo)bar matches bar when bar is preceded by foo
(?<=) - Positive Lookbehind    (?<=foo)bar matches bar when preceded by foo
```

> These next two I don't get...

```
(?=                  look ahead to see if there is:
 [-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?     any character of: '-', '_', 'a' to 'z', 
                     'A' to 'Z', '0' to '9' (0 or more times)
  [A-Z]              any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
)                    end of look-ahead
```

Same concept with `(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[a-z])` except your matching any character of `a` to `z`

Next, `\s` matches whitespace, and `\S` matches non-whitespace.

```
(?=                  look ahead to see if there is:
 [-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?     any character of: '-', '_', 'a' to 'z',
                     'A' to 'Z', '0' to '9' (0 or more times)
 [0-9]               any character of: '0' to '9'
)                    end of look-ahead
\S                   non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
```

The following quantifiers are recognized.

```
*      Match 0 or more times
+      Match 1 or more times
?      Match 1 or 0 times
{n}    Match exactly n times
{n,}   Match at least n times
{n,m}  Match at least n but not more than m times
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

You are right split them up by the `(?= ... )` expressions which are [look-aheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  The only other key thing to note is the use of `?` which is better explained by searching for regex [greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

So `^(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[A-Z])` essentially reads as: *look ahead and find any alphanumeric character and/or hyphen or underscore UNTIL you find at least one uppercase letter.*

`(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[a-z])` ditto: *... lowercase letter.*

`(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[0-9])` ditto: *... number.*

The escape sequence `\S` is actually what is performing the "match" assuming the look-aheads have been satified. Uppercase `\S{6,12}` reads as: *match any non-whitespace character sequence between 6 and 12 characters long.*

Comment: So if i mix the tree groups of (?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[A-Z]) where the end of each group specifies either a-z small, A-Z big and 0-9 numbers.  Where does the regxp look for all the other chars that are to be eg. 6 to 12 long.  So im just thinking, did i miss that part? :)

Comment: (?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[A-Z]) This would mean [-_a-zA-Z0-9]* zero or more of those... what does that have to do with [A-Z] which implicit means capital letters?

Comment: to make my logic clear here.. %^(-_a-zA-Z0-9)[haveTocontain,1,A-Z0-9]$%  ... i know i just inventet some new stuff here, but what im saying is.. its a very very odd waying of asking for 1 capital and 1 number in a string by splitting it up in to 3 groups..do you understand where i am struggeling? :)

Comment: Because at the start of the string you aren't guaranteed to have any particular character so you need to look *amongst* a set of every allowable character in a non-greedy search until you get to the one you are looking for which in that look-ahead is an upper case letter.  Because it's a look ahead it's zero length - so it "passes" but does not "match" anything, at which point it moves onto the next expression - again, from the start of the string.  Does that make sense?